# WPF DataGrid sort when Item source on DataGrid changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, datagrid

Does anyone know how I can sort a Datagrid when the Itemsource of the grid changes? i.e. if I have a DataGrid of products, and another grid of product versions, when I select a product, the ItemSource of the product version DataGrid will change so I would like to do a sort before the data appears inside the Product Versions DataGrid.

The way I do the sorting at the moment is.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsProductVersions" 
     Source="{Product.ProductVersions, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
     Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
     <!--<CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Build1"  Direction="Descending"/>
     </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>-->
  </CollectionViewSource>
```

I think I need to use

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgProductVersion.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

However, I need an event which basically means "Run this code once a new itemsource is applied to the table.

Cheers

Comment: How do you set `ItemSource` of version DataGrid? Can you show XAML of this DataGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some stage, I'm guessing that you set a collection as the `ItemsSource` property value for your `CollectionViewSource`. Why don't you just sort it using `LinQ` *before* you assign it to the `CollectionViewSource`?:

```
SomeCollection = new ObservableCollection(SomeCollection.OrderBy(i => i.Build));
```

You *can* refresh a `CollectionViewSource` directly, but it isn't generally what users want because it does a complete refresh... you could try something like this:

```
(dgProductVersion.ItemsSource as ListCollectionView).Refresh();
```

A third option can be found in the [ItemsControl: 'E' is for Editable Collection](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/) on the Dr. WPF website.

Comment: I like the LINQ Idea, I assign the collectionViewSource in XAML, is there a way I can still do this via LINQ? I have updated my code in question. Cheers

Comment: No worries, I have done it, good idea to do it in the MVVM with LINQ. Cheers!